# Details about using packages with Wolfram Player

Tags: packages, contexts, wolfram-player

Is there a definitive document that describes the differences between what's allowed in Mathematica and Wolfram Player?

I'm seeing differences in behavior between references to variables in packages (using Contexts). I want to make sure the code I write will run correctly either under Mathematica or under the Wolfram Player.